# Python: Object method cannot see changes to a self.variable made by another method

Tags: python, inheritance, methods, scope, variable-assignment

I have two functions working on the same data, so I thought it made sense to create a class instead. But I'm having trouble seeing the changes made to a self.variable in the first method from within the second method.

```
class Settings:
    def __init__(self):
        self.settings_to_change = {}

    def get_default(self, **kwargs):   
        self.settings_to_change.update('setting': True})
        log(f'Settings to be changed: {self.settings_to_change})
        
    def set_default(self, **kwargs):
        log(f'Settings to be changed: {self.settings_to_change})


settings = Settings()

settings.get_default()
# output: Settings to be changed: {'setting': True}

settings.set_default()
# output: Settings to be changed: {}
```

I thought that using self. for the variable and initialising it when the object is created would mean that I can update the variable in one object method, then see the updates within the second. But it seems to revert to the initialised value.

I'm not sure if it's to do with how my object is being called.

I have an application that can run python scripts on command.

First, when a settings window is open: `RunScript(script.py,action=settings.get_default)`

Then `script.py` is like so:

```
from resources.lib.script.actions import *
from resources.lib.script.settings import Settings
from resources.lib.utilities import *


class Main:
    def __init__(self, *args):
        settings = Settings()
        try:
            self.params = dict(arg.split('=', 1) for arg in args)
        except:
            self.params = {}
        function = eval(self.params['action'])
        function(**self.params)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Main(*sys.argv[1:])
```

First execution works fine, but then when the settings window is closed it calls: `RunScript(script.py,action=settings.set_default)` and that's when I see in my log that self.settings_to_change looks empty.

Comment: Your script has `settings_to_change` in two places where you probably wanted `self.settings_to_change`.  Were those actual typos in the code?

Comment: Wait a minute.  If `RunScript` starts a new copy of Python each time, then clearly you must understand that the instances are totally unrelated.  There's no object sharing between processes.

Comment: Thanks [Tim Roberts](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1883316/tim-roberts) -  apologies when simplifying the code for sharing I accidentally removed the selfs. I've edited them back in. Your second point could be it, I'm not sure to be honest as this is my first coding project, but will try to investigate along those lines. If that's teh case I guess having a class doesn't really help and I need to save the output I need somewhere else where it can be accessed, such as a file.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify self each time, otherwise its going to look for a local scope variable.

```
class Settings:
    def __init__(self):
        self.settings_to_change = {}

    def get_default(self, **kwargs):   
        self.settings_to_change.update({'setting': True})
        print(f'Settings to be changed: {self.settings_to_change}')
        
    def set_default(self, **kwargs):
        print(f'Settings to be changed: {self.settings_to_change}')


settings = Settings()

settings.get_default()
# output: Settings to be changed: {'setting': True}

settings.set_default()
# output: Settings to be changed: {} 

#output
Settings to be changed: {'setting': True}
Settings to be changed: {'setting': True}
```

As a side note, why is your `get_default` setting and your `set_default` getting?

Comment: Thanks for the reply [Shorn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/21169587/shorn) - sorry I accidentally removed the selfs when simplifying my code to share here. I added them back in and can confirm my issue persists, but [Tim Roberts](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1883316/tim-roberts) suggests it may be due to how I am running the script, that these methods are not being called in a shared instance.

Comment: To your second question, the dictionary I am updating in 'get_default' is the list of settings values that do not match recommended settings. I want to be able to pass this to my set_settings method so I am only over-writing the correct settings. This is my approach to letting the user choose and apply a recommended settings profile in effect.